# How to get value of JSON array or object in VB.net?

Tags: php, json, vb.net

I have JSON file having following data. I just want to get the data of "naming" and "unit". Please assist me how to do this in VB.net?

```
[
        {
            "customerId": "999",
            "deviceId": "XXX999",
            "searchDeviceId": "D_XXX999",
            "utc": "2016-04-28T03:37:00.000Z",
            "lat": 22.5691,
            "lng": 120.3058,
            "sensors": [
                {
                    "naming": "ABC123",
                    "factor": null,
                    "unit": "k",
                    "period": null
                },
                {
                    "naming": "XYZ123",
                    "factor": null,
                    "unit": "c",
                    "period": null
                },
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For C# :

```
JObject jResults = JObject.Parse("JsonString");
String naming = jResults["sensors"]["naming "];
String unit = jResults["sensors"]["unit "];
```

For VB:

```
Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse("JsonString")
Dim naming As [String] = jResults("sensors")("naming ")
Dim unit As [String] = jResults("sensors")("unit ")
```

You can achieve like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm getting this error [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTeaderException:Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.]. I changed to JArray but still getting error [System.ArgumentException:Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "sensors".Int32 array index expexted.]

Comment: Have you add the newtonsoft.dll ?

Comment: JArray jResults = JArray.Parse("JsonString");

var tem = jResults [0]["sensors"]["naming"].ToString();

Comment: Thank you very much but having same error. I have installed JSON.NET. If you don't mind could you please give me sample code?

Comment: I used which was I posted.

Comment: Hi Chetan Sanghani, is it possible to get only keys like customerId, deviceId, searchDeviceId......... ?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case people are looking to loop through multiple JSON Array or Object in vb.net using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

```
 request = url
 request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)

            'Get response
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            ' Get the response stream into a reader  
            reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim JSONresponseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

            ' Parse the content into a json object
            Dim json As String = JSONresponseFromServer
            Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
            Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList

            For Each item As JProperty In data
                item.CreateReader()
                Select Case item.Name
             Case "sensors" 'each record is inside the entries array
                     For Each Entry As JObject In item.Values
                       Dim naming As String = Entry("naming ").ToList.Item(0)
                       Dim factor As String = Entry("factor").ToList.Item(0)
' you can continue listing the array items untill you reach the end of you array

             Next
        End Select
 Next
```

If the Json object item is not in an array and you just want the items it returns

```
   For Each item As JProperty In data
       item.CreateReader()
             Dim customerId As String = ser("customerId")
             Dim deviceIdAs String = ser("deviceId")
   next
```

I was getting an error using the 'Chetan Sanghani' answer with the brackets around string ex [String]

Answer (score 0):

Use Jarray its better

see this example and try to make it on your json data
its clear .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).