# Need assistance extracting dynamic text between curly braces

Tags: vb.net

```
"keys": [{"key": "da0a1c781f5647e1b32b517d9a9afdfc:4f216ee9d53e1bf7767b6fcf140d799f"}]}
```

This is the code that is generated by the application I'm trying to finish.  I'm trying to figure out how to take the key from between the quotation marks and have it displayed in another text box in the application.

Can anyone assist with this?

I was able to find this code:

```
Public Function extract_value(str As String) As String
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer
Dim midBit As String
openPos = Instr(str, "{")
closePos = Instr(str, "}")
midBit = mid(str, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)
If openPos <> 0 And Len(midBit) > 0 Then
extract_value = midBit
Else
extract_value = "F"
End If
End Function
```

But now I can't append this to my text box once I click the button.  Can anyone help?

Comment: That's a JSON string missing a `{` at the beginning. Parse it as JSON instead of trying to do the work manually.

Comment: How do I parse it as JSON?

Comment: [How to get value of JSON array or object in VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36905873/8967612)

Comment: JSON seems even more complicated

Comment: When you have put back the missing leading brace `{`, it's just `Dim key = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(YourJsonString)("keys")(0)("key")` (for the first key in the array)

Comment: But what would I use in place of YourJsonString if it changes every time?